# Local ring along an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Atiyah and MacDonald's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra", in the examples in the first section of chapter 3 ("Rings and Modules of Fractions"), the author mentions that the local ring $A_\mathfrak{p}$, where $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, can be identified with the rational functions that are defined on almost all points of the variety $V(\mathfrak{p})$.
Equivalently, it means that if $g\notin p$, then $g(x)\neq 0$ for almost all points in $V(p)$.

But I do think it is possible to have $h(x)=0$ for all $x \in V(\mathfrak{p})$ for some $h\notin p$ since the variety is only the intersection of all the zeros of functions in $\mathfrak{p}$, and we define the variety based on $\mathfrak{p}$ so it does not restrict the functions that are not in $\mathfrak{p}$. Can someone give me a direction on how to prove this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $k$ algebraically closed?

Comment: @sykhic Yes, I jsut assume it from the context although the author does not explicitly mention that.

Comment: In that case then then for all ideals, J, we have that the ideal of V(J) is the radical of J.  In your case J is prime and so the ideal of the variety is $p$.  This follows from the Nullstellensatz.  You can find lots of proofs of this theorem online.

Comment: @sykhic Thank you very much. I think I understand it now.

Comment: But it seems that that we can only deduce that every function in the ring after localization is well-defined at some point in the variety, but not like what the book proposed: at all but finitely many points in the variety. Are they in some sense equivalent?

Comment: I don’t have the book in question.  Does it really say “all but finitely many points”?  Consider $k[x,y,z]$ with $p=(x)$ and $g = y-z$.  The infinitely many points $(0, a, a)$ are in $V(p)$ and $g$ is not in $p$.

Comment: I think what "defined at almost all points of $V$" means here is that it is defined in a dense subset of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what the author means by "defined at almost all points of $V$" is "defined in a dense subset of $V$".

This is indeed true. For any $g \notin \mathfrak{p}$, the set $D(g) = \{x \in k^n \mid g(x) \ne 0\}$ is open in $k^n$ with the Zariski topology, and so $D(g) \cap V(\mathfrak{p})$ is open in $V(\mathfrak{p})$.
Furthermore, it is nonempty because $g \notin \mathfrak{p}$ so the Nullstellensatz implies that $g$ must be nonzero somewhere in $V(\mathfrak{p})$.
But $V(\mathfrak{p})$ is irreducible (because $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime), so this subset is dense.